# Android force location update on app load - fusedlocationproviderclient

Tags: android, fusedlocationproviderclient

I am facing an issue where as I cannot get any location info in my app until another app such as Google Maps is loaded and triggers a location update.

IN order to solve this I thought of starting location updates when onCreate() fires and then immediately stop it whe  a location is received. I am using the following code in onCreate() method:

```
// Location client
        final FusedLocationProviderClient locationClient = getFusedLocationProviderClient(this);
        if (checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            locationClient.requestLocationUpdates(new LocationRequest().setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_BALANCED_POWER_ACCURACY).setInterval(500).setFastestInterval(500), new LocationCallback() {
                @Override
                public void onLocationResult(LocationResult locationResult) {
                    super.onLocationResult(locationResult);
                    locationClient.removeLocationUpdates(new LocationCallback() {

                    });
                }

                @Override
                public void onLocationAvailability(LocationAvailability locationAvailability) {
                    super.onLocationAvailability(locationAvailability);
                }
            }, null);
        }
```

After this still no locations are being stored until I run Google Maps. Any suggestion appreciated!

Comment: Shouldn't be you changing the code checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED to checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED?
Also, you are just requesting location updates, not querying the current location, which is why the callback is triggered only when some other app queries for the location and there is a change in the same. You can also use getLastKnownLocation().

Comment: Oh dear!!!!! Yes indeed!!!! Too much programming!!!

Comment: Thanks. Changed it but still without success. Any suggestions?

Comment: Can you update the post with current code? Also please follow https://developer.android.com/training/location/change-location-settings